# Some keys not registering on TTY

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, tty

When working in any TTY (1-6), some of the keys on my laptop keyboard do not type anything. These keys work just fine in GUI. The 'Caps lock' indicator on my keyboard doesn't even light up when I push caps lock while in TTY. I can't even log into tty to do anything, as my username contains character that do not work. What could be causing the problem? How can I fix it? I have tried using a usb keyboard and the problem persists.

Edit: Here is output from

```
cat /etc/default/keyboard

XKBLAYOUT=us
BACKSPACE=guess
```

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version? I can confirm CapsLock LED behaviour on 18.04 and 20.04. About "username contains character that do not work" - which exactly characters? Do you have numerical keys block in the middle of keyboard? Have you tried to disable NumLock by pressing NumLock key?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.04, it isn't a NumLock issue. None of the numbers work, and the letters 'a' and 'm' do not work.

Comment: I have reported the problem with CapsLock key and LED to launchpad as [bug 1925141](https://pad.lv/1925141). Please add the output of `cat /etc/default/keyboard` to the question body. You may have wrong keyboard layout after boot.

Comment: Updated the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `/etc/default/keyboard` file looks different from default one. You miss the `XKBMODEL` field. See default file for reference:

> ```
> # KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE
>
> # Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.
>
> XKBMODEL="pc105"
> XKBLAYOUT="us"
> XKBVARIANT=""
> XKBOPTIONS=""
>
> BACKSPACE="guess"
> ```

You have to regenerate it by running

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

and then reboot.

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick!